# Submit Form when all fields completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form

```
<form method="post" name="lunch" id="lunch">

     <input type="number" id="people" name="people" onchange="calculo_lunch()" class="form-control">

     <input type="number" id="duration" name="duration" onchange="calculo_lunch()" class="form-control">

 </form>
```

And i use this jquery script to submit it

```
    $(function(){

        $("#lunch").submit(function(){

            //jquery code

            return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
        })
    });

    $('input[type="number"]').on('change', function() { $("#lunch").trigger('submit'); })
```

This submit my form when one of the fields is changed but now i need that this form triggers when both of the fields are completed

Comment: when both of the fields are completed means both fields have some value?

Comment: make a separate function that checks both inputs and add that to the inputs change event.

Comment: How are you defining "when a field is completed"? When there haven't been any keyboard presses for, say, 3 seconds?

Comment: Do you want the action on the change event? The form submits as soon as the second element is incremented (or decremented) by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will check each 'number' type input and count up the number that have some value.  If the number of inputs with values matches the number of inputs, the form submits.  This will work for any number of inputs, so if you add 10 more it will still work.

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('change', function() {
    //initialize counter
    var completed_fields = 0;

    //count up the number of completed number inputs
    $('#lunch').find('input[type="number"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()){
            completed_fields += 1;
        }
    });

    //test the number of completed fields vs the total number of fields
    if($('#lunch').find('input[type="number"]').length == completed_fields)
    {
        $("#lunch").trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var fields = $('input[type="number"]'); //store all fields ref

fields.change(function() {
   if(fields.filter(function(){
      return !!$(this).val();
   }).length == field.length) { //all fields has values.
      $("#lunch").submit();
   }
})
```

Comment: @davyt:  To be honest, this is a better solution.  It does the same thing that mine does with less code.  It's just not commented as thoroughly as mine is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $("#lunch").submit(function(){
        //check if both values are whatever you need -->
        if (parseInt($('#people').val()) > 0 && parseInt($('#duration').val()) > 0){
              //jquery code
        }else{
             return;
        }

                   }
    });
        return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
    })
});

$('input[type="number"]').on('change', function() { $("#lunch").trigger('submit'); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that each input has a value before triggering the submit event and bind your onChange event within DOM ready.

```
$(function(){

    $("#lunch").submit(function(){

        //jquery code

        return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
    }); // end submit
    $('input[type="number"]').on('change', function() { 
        if( $('input[type="number"]').filter(function() { return this.value == ''; }).length === 0 ) {
            $("#lunch").trigger('submit');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use html5 required tag on the fields:

```
<input type="number" id="people" name="people" onchange="calculo_lunch()" class="form-control" required>
```

that should prevent submitting if field is empty..

Comment: This will prevent submitting, but it won't automatically submit, which is what OP wants.